# Python SQLAlchemy get matching row and next row where column is the same

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+-------------+
| id       | name     | date        |   
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 1        | John     | 2018-08-21  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 2        | James    | 2018-08-22  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 3        | John     | 2018-08-22  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 4        | Paul     | 2018-08-23  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
```

I'm looking for a query that, when you select `id = 1` it would return:

```
+----------+----------+-------------+
| id       | name     | date        |   
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 1        | John     | 2018-08-21  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 3        | John     | 2018-08-22  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
```

but when you select `id = 2` you would get:

```
+----------+----------+-------------+
| id       | name     | date        |   
+----------+----------+-------------+
| 2        | James    | 2018-08-22  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
```

So in other words, the query should get return the matching row by `id` and the next row where the name is the same.

I would I accomplish this in `sqlalchemy`.  All help appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you would need something like this suggests that you have a bad data base model design to begin with. Can you explain the purpose of such a query?

Comment: @zvone sure.  I gave a very simple example, but you can imagine the schema being more complex.  The app I'm building runs some operation daily, and there is functionality to see the difference in data between the two days. Therefore, I need the latest 2 entries for the user to compare the results.  If there the operation has only been done once, then obviously there is nothing to compare to.

Comment: But that should not take the next one by ID, it should sort by date and then limit the results to 2.

Comment: @zvone that wouldn't work, because I would get the same two results everytime.  I need to find the row from a certain id (or date) and compare that to the previous entry.  So if I want to compare today's results to yesterday's results, and last week's results to results 8 days ago. Sorting by date would also give me different results, unless I'm misunderstanding something

Answer (score 3):

To work with a relational database is to understand that *there is no next row,* no preset order. You need to request a particular order by sorting, then fetch as many records in that order as you need.

In this case, you use e.g. `.filter(the_table.c.name == "John")`, then `.order_by("id", "name")`, then `.limit(2)`. If you fetched two rows there were two records that match your constraint. There can be no records, or just one record.

Things become trickier if you have *multiple* sets of records for John, and want a particular subsequence. For that you might add a condition like `the_table.c.id >= certain_id`, or something similar for the date.

In general, your data model is lacking an explicit way to link several records into one sequence. You don't have a "sequence id", or "previous record id", or something like that which would help see several records as related. Maybe you can use the timestamp column for that, *if* it fits your  problem; it quite likely does not.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been much easier to provide answer after seeing your attempt. Below is code snippet which might help you to understand

```
subquery = session.query(Person.name.label('name')).subquery()
main_query = session.query(Person).join(subquery, Person.name==subquery.c.name).filter(Person.id==2).\
order_by(Person.id).limit(2)
```

The much cleaner approach would involve querying two times

```
get_name = session.query(Person).filter(Person.id==1).first()[0]
get_all_rows =session.query(Person).filter(Person.name==get_name).order_by(Person.id).limit(2)
```